# Why is this example a literal embedding？

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

[see the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gsLR.png)
It is from S.Hedman's a first course in logic.
I am confused with this example.
Why in function g the author uses notation f?
Also I thinks only g(a) = b, g(b) = e, g(c) = f(instead of d) and g(d) = c(instead of f) makes a literal embedding.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: typo...........

Comment: You have to review the def of *literal* (pag.28) and the first-order language for *graph* (pag.66).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you a lot for explanation, and sorry I don't have enough reputation to give a vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Long comment*

IMO there are typos: the definition of function $g : M → N$ must be:

> $g(A) = b, \ g(B) = e, \ g(C) = f, \text { and } g(D) = c$.

Having said that, why $f$ is **not** a *literal embedding*? Because (see **Def.2.50**) $f$ does **not** preserves all $\mathcal V$-formulas that are literals.

In the first structure we have $\lnot R(A,C)$, while in the second one we have $R(a,c)$, i.e. $R(f(A),f(C)$).